# Best way to check if Option contains a specific Some value?

Tags: rust, option-type

You can't do something such as:

```
if option.is_some() && option == 1 {
    // ...
}
```

Since if `option.is_some() == false` the 2nd comparison would error.

What is the best way to do something such as this?

What I'm doing right now:

```
if option.is_some() {
    if option == 1 {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pattern matching is a powerful tool, use it!  Instead of a regular `if`, use an `if let`:

```rust
if let Some(1) = option {
    // --snip--
}
```

For more information about pattern matching, please consult [The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html).

Comment: I previously (before the version I give in my question) was using the `match` keyword as such https://pastebin.com/dk1n48Lb . I suppose this does the same thing but more elegantly? Also could `if let` be used for a `>` comparison?

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light in The Book there's a very good explanation of the `if let`, when to use it over `match` or when to prefer the latter over the former, [an entire dedicated chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html)

Comment: I edited by above comment not sure if you saw my edit (sorry about that) to ask if `if let` could be used with a `>` or similar condition.

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light well, you could use a pattern like `Some(0..=3)` or even `Some(12..=<T as MaxValue>::MAX)` (or use the `MIN` depending on the type and your comparison `<` or `>`).  You could also use a `match` with an extra `if` filter as part of its pattern, or even `if option.map_or(false, |i| i > 2)`.  Look into the reference I linked in my answer.

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light simpler https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=a0c0a6829c3049d49289b67a09ec16ae

Answer (score 7):

The pattern matching is the right solution, but if you want a `bool`, you can use the equality operator:

```
fn main() {
    let maybe_int = Some(123);
    let contains_123: bool = maybe_int == Some(123);

    assert!(contains_123);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
option.contains(&1);
```

using either

```
#![feature(option_result_contains)]
```

or

```
[dependencies]
option-ext = "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need no dependencies or unstable features for a concise check.
To check if your `Option<T>` contains a specific `T` value you can also use the `matches!` macro.

So in your case you would write `if matches!(option, 1) { todo!() }`

Here a full example with a `Option<bool>`:

```
        if matches!(t, Some(true)) {
            println!("This is true!");
            assert!(true)
        }

        let t = Some(false);

        if matches!(t, Some(true)) {
            // never enters here
            assert!(false)
        }
```