# Check if Option<String> is Some(my_string)

Tags: rust

I'd like to know what is the most idiomatic way of checking if a `q: Option<String>` that I have has the value of a particular string that I have in `my_string: String`. So the most straightforward solution is:

```rs
if q.is_some() && q.unwrap() == my_string
```

Another one I can think of:

```rs
if q.unwrap_or_default() == my_string
```

but this wouldn't work in the corner case of `my_string` being empty.

Another one:

```rs
match q {
  Some(s) if s == my_string => {
    ...
  },
  _ => {},
}
```

but this is very verbose.

Is there something simpler, like some clever `if let`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to check if Option contains a specific Some value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317716/best-way-to-check-if-option-contains-a-specific-some-value)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

check it directly:

```
if Some(my_string) == q {
}
```

or (to keep `my_string` alive)

```
if Some(&my_string) == q.as_ref() {
}
```

There will be (probably) a `contains()` function in future rust versions which can be used like

```
if q.contains(&my_string) {
}
```

It is more flexible because it allows to compare different datatypes (when they implement `PartialEq`).  See https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62358

Comment: Wow, so simple. I'm sure I tried doing something like this but I got some terrifying errors about ownership being transferred in and out of the option, and I resigned. I was apparently doing something wrong.

Comment: `my_string` cannot be used any more after the test

Comment: Thanks for the update. This was causing the ownership problems that I had, but later I refactored something and no longer needed it. Anyway, the option with `as_ref()` is probably the "most right" solution.

Answer (score 2):

I really like the answer provided by @ensc but it **consumes** `my_string`; here is a version that does not.

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_string = String::from("abcd");
    let q1: Option<String> = Some(String::from("abcd"));
    let q2: Option<String> = Some(String::from("abc"));
    let q3: Option<String> = None;
    // if Some(my_string) == q1 { // this will CONSUME my_string
    if Some(&my_string) == q1.as_ref() {
        println!("The same {:?}", q1);
    }
    // if Some(my_string) == q2 { // this will CONSUME my_string
    if Some(&my_string) == q2.as_ref() {
        println!("The same {:?}", q2);
    }
    // if Some(my_string) == q3 { // this will CONSUME my_string
    if Some(&my_string) == q3.as_ref() {
        println!("The same {:?}", q3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.70 you can use `is_some_and`.

```
if q.is_some_and(|s| s == myString) {
}
```

See [std::option::Option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_some_and)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if let`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = Some("abc".to_string());
    if let Some("abc") = s.as_ref().map(|s: &String| s as &str) {
        println!("Ok")
    }
}
```

Comment: Right side can be replaced with `s.as_deref()` - https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref.

Comment: This only works when `"abc"` is a literal, you cannot pass a variable there, and I need to pass a variable.

Answer (score 0):

On the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html) :

```
let some_u8_value = Some(0u8);
match some_u8_value {
    Some(3) => println!("three"),
    _ => (),
}
```

Is equivalent of :

```
if let Some(3) = some_u8_value {
    println!("three");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it only works when `3` is a literal, you cannot put there a variable. It would just shadow that variable with a new one, containing the actual value of the option.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to access  `my_string` in the code block that is guarded by the `if`-statement, you can use the `matches!` macro to check for equality of two `Options`:

```
if matches!(q, Some(my_string)) {
    // do something
}
```